# C function address in nm output and runtime

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
    printf("hello, world!\r\n");
}

void main()
{
    test();
    printf("%p\r\n", test);
}
```

When running this code on Ubuntu 18.04, the function address of test is 0x565785b0, and the nm command gives the address of test 0x000005b0. But on Ubuntu 16.04, the function addresses of test are always the same.

Ubuntu 18.04: gcc version 5.5, nm 2.30, kernel 4.15.0-33
Ubuntu 16.04: gcc version 5.4, nm 2.26.1, kernel 4.15.0-33

Could anyone, please, explain when these addresses are the same, when are different? And is it possible to make them always same?

Comment: Are you sure about the kernel version for your Ubuntu 16.04?  What you quote is correct for 18.04, but I think 16.04 was using an older kernel.

Comment: Why does it matter to you?  What are you hoping to do with the knowledge of the addresses?  There is a thing called ASLR (address space layout randomization).  I'm not certain it's a factor in the changing address, but it might be.

Comment: Yes, it has a relation with ASLR. In Ubuntu 18.04, gcc is configured with --enable-default-pie option by default. When compiled with gcc -no-pie, the addresses are always the same. Thanks@JonathanLeffler.